# Picasso and ImageLoader android

Tags: java, android, universal-image-loader, picasso

Sorry for my English. First, I used the library `Picasso` it's a good library, there are many possibilities but it is not stored in the cache. Then I learned about the library `ImageLoader` excellent library that can store images in the cache. But I first made the application on examples `Picasso`. Here for example I did blur image in `Picasso`:

```
//code
    Picasso.with(context).load(profileList.get(0).getImage())
            .resize(100, 100)
            .centerInside()
            .into(target);
//code
private Target target = new Target() {
    @Override
        public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {       
            Bitmap b;
            b = fastblur(bitmap, 3); // fastblur method blur image
            int color = Color.parseColor("#8C2d569c")          
            foneImage.setColorFilter(color); //set filter
            foneImage.setImageBitmap(b); //and set image
        }

        @Override
        public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
        @Override
        public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    };
```

But now I do not know how to move this code to `ImageLoader`. Below is how I used `ImageLoader` and load the image in `ImageView`

```
    mImageLoader.displayImage(profileList.get(0).getImage(), imageProfile, null, new ImageLoadingListener() {

                @Override
                public void onLoadingStarted(String arg0, View arg1) {
                    Log.e("Script", "OnLoadeing");
                }

                @Override
                public void onLoadingFailed(String arg0, View arg1, FailReason arg2) {
                    Log.e("Script", "OnLoadeingComplete");
                }

                @Override
                public void onLoadingComplete(String arg0, View arg1, Bitmap arg2) {
                    Log.e("Script", "OnLoadeingFailed");
                }

                @Override
                public void onLoadingCancelled(String arg0, View arg1) {
                    Log.e("Script", "OnLoadeingStarted");
                }
              }, new ImageLoadingProgressListener() {

                @Override
                public void onProgressUpdate(String uri, View view, int current, int total) {
                    Log.e("Script", "OnProgressUpdate" + uri + " " + total);
                }
            })

;
```

How do I add a method `fastblur (bitmap, 3);` in `mImageLoader`?

**UPD:**

**Its answer for my question**

```
mImageLoader.displayImage(profileList.get(0).getImage(), foneImage, null, new ImageLoadingListener() {

            @Override
            public void onLoadingStarted(String arg0, View arg1) {
                Log.e("Script", "OnLoadeing");
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadingFailed(String arg0, View arg1, FailReason arg2) {
                Log.e("Script", "OnLoadeingComplete");
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadingComplete(String arg0, View arg1, Bitmap arg2) {
                Bitmap b;
                b = fastblur(arg2, 5);
                int color = Color.parseColor("#8C2d569c"); //The color u want             
                foneImage.setColorFilter(color);
                foneImage.setImageBitmap(b);
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadingCancelled(String arg0, View arg1) {
                Log.e("Script", "OnLoadeingStarted");
            }
          }, new ImageLoadingProgressListener() {

            @Override
            public void onProgressUpdate(String uri, View view, int current, int total) {
                Log.e("Script", "OnProgressUpdate" + uri + " " + total);
            }
        });
```

Comment: what you want to do with Picasso Library. ??

Comment: post answer in answer post not in question itself

Answer (score 2):

You should inheritance the prototype of mImageLoader if this is not a final class, and then add your method at this new class.